# why i got the same icon when use different font Awesome swift5

Tags: swift, font-awesome

hello every one actually I download .ttf format of font awsome , and when I use different code inside of u{}  I got just question mark in simulator and here is my code and simulator :

[image]

Comment: set font : UIFont.init(name: "FontAwesome5Free-Solid", size: 30)

Comment: I think you should provide .png type icons

Comment: Quick question: Does `UIFont(name:...)` you wrote is `nil`? If yes, what's the real post script name of the font (not the font file name).

Comment: @RajaKishan hi brother actually I try this but also I have question mark

Comment: @Kudos so could you tell me how could I provide these type?

Comment: @Larme no its not nil